# How do you lock groups of vertices in an object in relation to each other so that when scaling the object those vertices don't scale?

Tags: vertices, scale

I'm using blender 2.82. I have made a cabinet door in which the side rails are 2 1/4 inches wide. I would like to lock all the vertices in each corner in their current distance from each other so that if I scale this door height or width, the rails stay 2 1/4 inches wide no matter the size of the door. So for example I could scale it from 16"x20 3/4" to 18"x6 1/4" and keep my rails all the same 2 1/4in wide. At this point I have been going into edit mode and selecting the vertices of one side of the door dragging to the desired width and then the vertices on top or bottom and changing the height. It keeps it all in proportion but is tedious and slow. Being able to type the dimensions into the transform tool would be way faster. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: To maybe show more clearly what I meant:
[image]

All the rails need to stay the same width no matter the door size. To speed up door creation since I have lots of doors to make, I would like to type the dimension into the transform box rather than going into edit mode grabbing one side of the door and moving it to the desired width or height. If I could lock together each group of corner vortexes, then scaling would only lengthen the edges between the corners, but not change the scale of the corners themselves.

Currently, tranforming with the transform dialog box does this:

[image]

Changing the height of the door on the left to the door height of the door on the right makes the overall dimension the same, but ruins the rails.

The rendered door:

[image]

Comment: Try a push/pull operation instead of a scale.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the type of solution you're looking for but have you tried selecting the outer edges of the door and assigning them to a vertex group, like so...

[image]

and then you can select and deselect that specific region (without affecting the frame in the inside) and scale in edit mode in the 3d view...

[image]

Comment: I did test this out to see if I could make a modified version of your idea work, but unless I am doing it wrong, it isn't working (I could very well be doing it wrong, I am brand new to Blender). And I was hoping to work in object mode, using the transform dialog box, so I could just type in my door dimension and have my new door with the rails all properly sized and only have to worry about the texture scaling. Currently I can do that and have the exterior of the door properly sized, but the rails will not be the same width.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are going to get that without scripting. I sold CAD/CAM systems for twenty years, the bulk for the cabinet industry, what you are talking about is parametrics and you find that in manufacturing software. You just have to resize the door while it is on the cabinet for relation. go to wireframe/xray mode in edit, group the vertex' on an outside stile and stretch it to the edge of the cabinet or, in the case of a top or bottom rail you group the top or bottom vertice' and stretch to height. For a pair of doors I create the doors paired already, place in the middle of the face of the cabinet then stretch the outside vertices to the edges. If it is a cabinet here and a cabinet there, not that big a deal. You may be able to use shape keys if you can add some variables as a formula but, that's basically scripting and you would be creating a lot of steps that can mess up. If you are trying to design custom kitchen cabinets on a regular basis, you are better off using software made for that purpose.

So, short of learning Python, you are going to be jumping through a lot of hoops if you are trying to automate the process...best to just adjust the vertices IMO, it's what I do.

Another thing, I cannot think of a single reason to be using version 2.82, you need to learn with the newsest tools or you are going to be asking a lot of questions that have already been solved in later versions and leave a lot of tools on the table that can make work a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple **Geometry Node modifier** set up to resize your object:

[image]

The Sign is the **Math Node** with **Sign** operation.

With the Vector input in your modifier you can offset the vertices in your model instead of scaling them.